# color skin icons but monochrome toolbar because plugin icons are black and white in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

For CKEditor, I have a color skin but am getting a monochrome toolbar.  There seems to be a conflict between the color icons under "skin" and the black-and-white icons under the individual plugins.

The skin is "moonocolor" and the color icons are under:

```
{CKEDITOR}/skins/moonocolor/icons/
```

But there are black-and-white icons under the respective:

```
{CKEDITOR}/plugins/{plugin_name}/icons/
```

I want color.  What do I need to do?  I thought that core/resourcemanager.js handled this type of stuff.

I should add that I am using the full source version of the product; lots of little files.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

Problem was that wrong icons appear in the toolbar.  I selected a skin, and the files are present, but are icons are not being used in the toolbar.  Config file "config.js" was built with the correct specification:

```
config.skin = 'moonocolor';
```

But just now, I succeeded in getting the CKEditor toolbar to use the icons.  First I went into the skins directory, in my case, this was "moonocolor".

```
$  cd moonocolor
```

In that directory, there is a program file called "skin.js".  I edited that. (My editor is "gvim".)

```
$  gvim skin.js
```

At the bottom of the script, there is an anonymous function with immediate execution, except that it is all commented out.  To help you identify this function, note that it includes the following:

```
(function() {
    var icons = ('...long string listing plugin names...').split( ',' );

    var iconsFolder = CKEDITOR.getUrl( CKEDITOR.skin.path() + 'icons/' + ( CKEDITOR.env.hidpi ? 'hidpi/' : '' ) );

    for ( var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++ ) {
    CKEDITOR.skin.addIcon( icons[ i ], iconsFolder + icons[ i ] + '.png' );
    }
})();
```

Uncomment the entire function.   When CKEditor starts up, it will find this file and run it, and at that time, this function will immediately execute.  (For readers not familiar with JavaScript, here's why it executes: The parenthesis surrounding the function definition, and the other parenthesis following that, together work to cause immediate execution.)  The reason that CKEditor finds this file in this subdirectory is because you told CKEditor about the subdirectory in the config file; see "config.skin = '...'" above.

The "for()" loop calls "addIcon()" for every plugin mentioned in the list.  The call to "addIcon()" specifies the desired subdirectory, via "CKEDITOR.skin.path()".  For each of the listed plugins, the desired "skins" subdirectory (in my case ".../skins/moonocolor") gets registered as the preferred source for an icon.

In that script, near that function, there are some comments that should be read.  The comments explain that in the production version, versus development version, the icons would have displayed automatically.  (I assume this is a reference to "minified" versus full source files.)